# SharePoint Online (Office 365) Alert email

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online, office-365, email, alert

In SharePoint Online (Office 365) I want to create a new list that does the following:

- We want to be able to put questions up on to the site, then assign the question to one of the site users. Once the question is assigned to an individual we would like an email to be sent to this user. This will mean that all users you know when an individual questions has been assigned to them.

I have created a new list with the following:

- Title - Single line of text
- Assigned to - Person or Group
- Question - Multiple lines of text
- Priority - Choice

I am hoping this can be done without creating a workflow but if a workflow is the best option I can use it.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use workflow, if you don't want to. Start with a fresh SharePoint task list, and configure it to send e-mail to assignees. You can name the task list the way you want and add site columns according to your needs. No workflow is needed.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I set up a new task list and set the email notification under the advanced settings to "send email to ownership assigned" I then tested this and no email came to me. Am I missing something??

Comment: @NPL Raise a support request in Office 365 Admin Center. They will help you. (Just check that you have a valid e-mail address in your user profile first).